# Content is not shown at angular.js web application while Hosting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-applications, web, web-hosting

I'm new at this,
I built an angular.js app and now I want to host it,
I tried both on google drive or firebase but in both cases the html 
is shown, but the information that loads on angular dosen't show..
Do I Have to develop a server side on node.js?

What can I do?
Thanks.

Comment: Angular does not require a backend server app unless you build features that depend on one.  Have you tried putting your code in a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/), or a similar tools, so you could test and share it easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need a http server to host your angular.js app, since angular.js need dynamically load the js file but it is not allowed to access the js file on file system directly. Suggest using this [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) to host. It's very convenient. Or simply copy your angular.js code to IIS or Nginx, Apache, Tomcat, etc ...